# WordPress - redirect all pages to other domain and exception homepage and wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I need help with WordPress redirect. I think, that the simplest way is make this with htaccess file.
I want 301 redirect all pages from my site www.domain.com to subdomain web.domain.com, but I want have exception for homepage www.domain.com and for wordpress admin in www.domain.com/wp-admin/... and www.domain.com/wp-login.php

I have the basic wordpress htaccess settings:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule !^(wp-admin(/.*)?|wp-login\.php)?$ http://web.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,NE,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help - I find, that I need both wp admin so I make this settings:

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/wpinstall(/.*)$    
RewriteRule (.*) http://web.domain.cz/$1 [R=301,QSA]
```

And I install wp to subfolder wpinstall